# MVC page not loading - The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, global

I just created an empty MVC project and added a masterpage and 1 view(Index). I also created a Controller(HomeController). I also right clicked on Index.aspx view and set this as startup.

However and error is showing up when running the project - "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Views/Index.aspx"

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Index

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    Test
</asp:Content>
```

MasterPage

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Test</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div class="page">
       <div id="header">
        </div>
   <div id="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Global

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: Your view looks like asp.net but not mvc page. Also you need to add your view to /Views/Home/Index.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try and navigate to `/Home/Index`

```
http://localhost:PORT/Home/Index
```

You've added your Controller `HomeController` this will match the default MVC routing and look for the `Index` Action Method within the Home Controller.  Also ensure that the Home View is within a folder called Home under the Views section of the application.

As a suggestion you may also want to use the Razor View Engine rather than the ASP View Engine.

Comment: I never used Razor and prefer use ASP at this stage. How can I look for Index from the controller, sorry im very new to this.

Comment: @user3430861 - Index is an action method on the Controller.  You've provided it in your question under `HomeController`.  By default MVC has a default route that matches the HomeController and Index action method.  Try navigating to '/Home/Index' like I've shown you in my answer.

Comment: I tried to rename the url to the one you provide but still with an error. Should I try to create a folder Home and move the view in the folder?

Comment: @user3430861 - yes that should do the trick, by default MVC looks at the View folders from the Controller name.

Comment: I created a folder named "Home" and moved the view in the folder, but still getting an error :( Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.aspx

Comment: however when I edited the link to this --> http://localhost:55389/Home/Index it works! how can I avoid getting the error!

Comment: @user3430861 - that's MVC convention.  You want to ensure that all routes are setup correctly within the `RouteConfig.cs` file (Under the App_Start folder). I would also implement a custom error page so your users don't see an 404 if they type an invalid route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99207/discussion-between-user3430861-and-darren-davies).

Comment: and could you please tell me how and from where can I access this and what to edit please

Comment: The `Views` folder is explicitly not available to access directly from the web. This is on purpose. In MVC, you don't serve up view files directly. Instead, you hit a route, which points to a particular controller and action, and then that action renders the view and returns it to the user. Right now, you're just trying to make it work like Web Forms, which is *completely* different.

Comment: Yes @ChrisPratt I know its wrong, but how can I fix it please?

Comment: Where to start? Fixing it requires a number of different changes, all involving *basic* knowledge of how MVC works. Go to http://asp.net/mvc and follow the tutorials.